# How does updating or inserting while looping through a result set affect the result set itself?

Tags: sql, plsql, resultset

suppose I fetch an RS, based on certain conditions and start looping though it , then , on certain situations , I update insert or delete records, which may have been part of this RS, using separate prepared statements.

How does this effect the result set ?  My inclination is to think that since the Statement which fetched this RS was executed earlier in the process, this RS will now be blind to the changes made by my prepared statements.

Pseudocode :

```
Preapare Statement ps1
execute ps1 -> get Result Set rs1
loop through rs1
    {
     Update or delete records using other prepared statements
    }
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. As the ResultSet object is already prepared, it does not matter what is happening at the backend to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read Consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#i61063)

**Oracle guarantees that the set of data seen by a statement is consistent with respect to a single point in time and does not change during statement execution (statement-level read consistency)**

That is why, If you have a query such as

```
insert into t
select * from t;
```

Oracle will simply duplicate all rows without going into an infinite loop or raising an error.

There are other implications because of this.

1) Oracle reads from the rollback segment to provide you with this read-consistent image of your data. So, if your rollback segments are nor correctly sized, or you commit across fetches, you'll get the "Snapshot too old" error, since your rollback data is no longer available.

*Ok , so if that is the case , is it possible to refresh it while making updates ? I mean aside from making the cursor updateable and using the inbuilt functions of the result set.*

2) Each query sees the data at the point of time **it** began. If by refresh you mean refiring the query, then the data you see might be different again, if you do commits in your pl/sql body or within a pl/sql loop or if some other transactions are running in your system concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. The result set of a query/cursor is kept by the database, even if you alter or remove the rows that are the base of this result set. So you are correct, it is blind to changes made after the statement is executed.

Comment: Ok , so if that is the case , is it possible to refresh it while making updates ?
 I mean aside from making the cursor updateable and using the inbuilt functions of the result set.

Comment: Not really, I think. But you could use `bulk collect into`, loop through that result, and modify each row. That way you can update the in memory representation of the result, although in this case, it is not updated in the database itself, so you'll have to combine the two. Of course, you could also execute the statement again, but that may take a lot of extra time (depending on the query) and you'll need to locate the right row again if you do not want to process rows twice.